# Do Bikers Have Passive Income?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

When part of a biker gang do your fellow bikers get paid hourly as a CEO's associates would? Or is there another passive form of income?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no regular income for playing as president, or being a member, no matter the rank, of a biker gang.